# Python read through file until match, read until next pattern

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

Python 2.4.3

I need to read through some files (can be as large as 10GB).  What I need it to do is go through the file until it matches a pattern.  Then print that line and every line after it until it matches another pattern.  At that point, resume reading through the file until the next pattern match.

For example.  file contains.

```
---- Alpha ---- Zeta
...(text lines)

---- Bravo ---- Delta
...(text lines)
```

etc.

If matching on ---- Alpha ---- Zeta, it should print ---- Alpha ---- Zeta and every line after that until it encounters ---- Bravo ---- Delta (or whatever other than ---- Alpha ---- Zeta), which it will read right on by it until it matches ---- Alpha ---- Zeta again.

The following matches what i'm looking for - but only prints the matching line - and not the text that follows it.

Any idea where I'm going wrong on it?

```
import re
fh = open('text.txt', 'r')

re1='(-)'   # Any Single Character 1
re2='(-)'   # Any Single Character 2
re3='(-)'   # Any Single Character 3
re4='(-)'   # Any Single Character 4
re5='( )'   # White Space 1
re6='(Alpha)'  # Word 1
re6a='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'   # Word 1 alternate
re7='( )'   # White Space 2
re8='(-)'   # Any Single Character 5
re9='(-)'   # Any Single Character 6
re10='(-)'  # Any Single Character 7
re11='(-)'  # Any Single Character 8
re12='(\\s+)'  # White Space 3
re13='(Zeta)'  # Word 2
re13a='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'  # Word 2 alternate


rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12+re13,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
rga =     re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6a+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12+re13a,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)


for line in fh:
    if re.match(rg, line):
        print line
        fh.next()
        while not re.match(rga, line):
            print fh.next()

fh.close()
```

and my example text file.

```
---- Pappa ---- Oscar
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eleifend imperdiet 
lacus quis imperdiet. Nulla erat neque, laoreet vel fermentum a, dapibus in sem. 
Maecenas elementum nisi nec neque pellentesque ac rutrum urna cursus. Nam non purus 
sit amet dolor fringilla venenatis. Integer augue neque, scelerisque ac dictum at, 
venenatis elementum libero. Etiam nec ante in augue porttitor laoreet. Aenean ultrices
pellentesque erat, id porta nulla vehicula id. Cras eu ante nec diam dapibus hendrerit
in ac diam. Vivamus velit erat, tincidunt id tempus vitae, tempor vel leo. Donec 
aliquam nibh mi, non dignissim justo.

---- Alpha ---- Zeta
Sed molestie tincidunt euismod. Morbi ultrices diam a nibh varius congue. Nulla velit
erat, luctus ac ornare vitae, pharetra quis felis. Sed diam orci, accumsan eget 
commodo eu, posuere sed mi. Phasellus non leo erat. Mauris turpis ipsum, mollis sed 
ismod nec, aliquam non quam. Vestibulum sem eros, euismod ut pharetra sit amet, 
dignissim eget leo.

---- Charley ---- Oscar
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
Aliquam commodo, metus at vulputate hendrerit, dui justo tempor dui, at posuere    
ante vitae lorem. Fusce rutrum nibh a erat condimentum laoreet. Nullam eu hendrerit 
sapien. Suspendisse id lobortis urna. Maecenas ut suscipit nisi. Proin et metus at 
urna euismod sollicitudin eu at mi. Aliquam ac egestas magna. Quisque ac vestibulum 
lectus. Duis ac libero magna, et volutpat odio. Cras mollis tincidunt nibh vel rutrum.
Curabitur fringilla, ante eget scelerisque rhoncus, libero nisl porta leo, ac
vulputate mi erat vitae felis. Praesent auctor fringilla rutrum. Aenean sapien ligula,
imperdiet sodales ullamcorper ut, vulputate at enim.


---- Bravo ---- Delta
Donec cursus tincidunt pellentesque. Maecenas neque nisi, dignissim ac aliquet ac,
vestibulum ut tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean ullamcorper dapibus accumsan. Aenean eros
tortor, ultrices at adipiscing sed, lobortis nec dolor. Fusce eros ligula, posuere
quis porta nec, rhoncus et leo. Curabitur turpis nunc, accumsan posuere pulvinar eget,
sollicitudin eget ipsum. Sed a nibh ac est porta sollicitudin. Pellentesque ut urna ut 
risus pharetra mollis tincidunt sit amet sapien. Sed semper sollicitudin eros quis 
pellentesque. Curabitur ac metus lorem, ac malesuada ipsum. Nulla turpis erat, congue 
eu gravida nec, egestas id nisi. Praesent tellus ligula, pretium vitae ullamcorper 
vitae, gravida eu ipsum. Cras sed erat ligula.


---- Alpha ---- Zeta
Cras id condimentum lectus. Sed sit amet odio eros, ut mollis sapien. Etiam varius 
tincidunt quam nec mattis. Nunc eu varius magna. Maecenas id ante nisl. Cras sed augue 
ipsum, non mollis velit. Fusce eu urna id justo sagittis laoreet non id urna. Nullam 
venenatis tincidunt gravida. Proin mattis est sit amet dolor malesuada sagittis. 
Curabitur in lacus rhoncus mi posuere ullamcorper. Phasellus eget odio libero, ut 
lacinia orci. Pellentesque iaculis, ligula at varius vulputate, arcu leo dignissim 
massa, non adipiscing lectus magna nec dolor. Quisque in libero nec orci vestibulum 
dapibus. Nulla turpis massa, varius quis gravida eu, bibendum et nisl. Fusce tincidunt 
laoreet elit, sed egestas diam pharetra eget. Maecenas lacus velit, egestas nec tempor 
eget, hendrerit et massa.
```

+++++++++++++++++++++ Update ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

The following code does work - it matches on the header type row - prints that and every line after it until the next header type pattern - which is that doesn't match, skips until the next header type pattern.

Only problem is - it's really really butt slow.  It takes about a minute to do through 10m lines.

```
re1='(-)'   # Any Single Character 1
re2='(-)'   # Any Single Character 2
re3='(-)'   # Any Single Character 3
re4='(-)'   # Any Single Character 4
re5='( )'   # White Space 1
re6='(Alpha)'  # Word 1
re6a='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'   # Word 1 alternate
re7='( )'   # White Space 2
re8='(-)'   # Any Single Character 5
re9='(-)'   # Any Single Character 6
re10='(-)'  # Any Single Character 7
re11='(-)'  # Any Single Character 8
re12='(\\s+)'  # White Space 3
re13='(Zeta)'  # Word 2
re13a='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'  # Word 2 alternate


rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12+re13,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
rga = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6a+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12+re13a,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)



linestop = 0
fh = open('test.txt', 'r')

for line in fh:
    if linestop == 0:
        if re.match(rg, line):
            print line
            linestop = 1
    else:
        if re.match(rga, line):
            linestop = 0
        else:
            print line

fh.close()
```

+++++++++ If I add a grep part to it first, i'm thinking that'll speed things up tremendously.  i.e. grep out - then run the above regex script.

I got os.system to work good - I can't see how to pass a regex match via pOpen

****** Final Update **********************

I'm calling this completed.  What I ended up doing was:

- Grep through the file using os.system - and writing the results out.
- reading the file in and using the re.match I have for above - printing out only the necessary items.

net result was it went from taking about 65 seconds to read through a 10 million line file - printing out the necessary items - to about 3.5 seconds.  I wish I could have figured out how to pass grep other than os.system - but maybe it's just not well implimented in python 2.4

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Are you really just trying to emulate the standard sed, awk, or perl behavior of **basic range operators** like `sed -ne '/foo/,/bar/p'` or `perl -ne 'print if /foo/ .. /bar/'` in python for want of a simple flipflop operator? Note that `..` and `...` are different, in that `..` tests the RHS as soon as the LHS goes true, whereas `...` waits till next time.  It’s just like the difference between `++i` and `i--`, which are two more basic operators that you nonetheless have to rewrite from scratch in python. What’s the overall application for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still matching against line, which doesn't change because you're still in the same iteration of the for loop.

Comment: that was actually the entire problem to begin with - but it did focus my attention to turn to a loop.  hense the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any need to use regex here. Not that they're that bad, but if you're looking for such a specific pattern, it's just overkill to use regex. Try something like this:

```
def record(filename, pattern):
    with open(filename) as file:
        recording = False
        for line in file:
            if line.startswith(pattern):
                yield line
                recording = not recording
            elif recording:
                yield line
```

Calling `record` with a filename and your pattern gives you a generator object yielding line after line. This is better when dealing with large files, so you don't have to slurp them in at once.

Printing your lines could then work like this - assuming your file is named `example.txt`:

```
for rec in record(filename, '---- Alpha ---- Zeta'):
    print rec
```

To be precise: The `record` generator yields the lines including the line breaks, so you might want to `join` them back together without any additional line breaks:

```
print "".join(list(record(filename, '---- Alpha ---- Zeta')))
```

Comment: Thank you Jellybean,  I got an invalid syntax on it.  And discovered the `with open` is a 2.5 or later.  I'm on 2.4.3 - sorry I should have put it in my post.

Comment: No problem, just replace the `with open(filename) as file` with `file = open(filename)`

Comment: I think it's close to working.  It starts printing at the first match of ---- Alpha ---- Zeta, but then prints everything after that until the next match of ---- Alpha ---- Zeta - which it does not print out.

Wouldn't this need some method to tell the generator to stop recording/yielding once it hits a non-matching ----  type line?

Comment: Ah, you want to output the matching lines in any case ... ok, I'll adjust the code to your needs.

Comment: thank you, but not much change.  It still prints out the non-matching lines, except now it prints the 2nd match of ---- Alpha ---- Zeta.

I managed to get some code working, i'll edit my question with what I'm using now.

Comment: I thought that was exactly what you wanted :)

Comment: Negative but I can see how you would have gotten that out of what I was looking for.

Given the above example text file.  It should print just the two paragraphs, each one directly under the ---- Alpha ---- Zeta....  The paragraphs under ---- Bravo ---- Oscar or ---- Charley ---- Oscar or ---- Bravo ---- Delta should not print

Comment: Thank you for all the effort - I just didn't see any way for this to work without pattern matching (i.e. regex) and I think it'll be difficult to improve over the speed I got in the end.  +1 for the insight into generators though.