# Python,how to extract text between two markers multiple times throughout text file?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text

I am having trouble extracting portions of text from txt file. Using python 3, I have the format below throughout the whole text file:

```
    integer stringOfFilePathandName.cpp string integer
    ...not needed text...
    ...not needed text...
    singleInteger( zero or one)
    ---------------------------------
    integer stringOfFilePathandName2.cpp string integer
    ...not needed text...
    ...not needed text...
    singleInteger( zero or one)
    ---------------------------------
```

The number of unwanted text lines is not stable for each pattern occurence. **I need to save the *stringOfFilePathandName.cpp* and the  *singleInteger* value, if possible to a dictionary, like
 {stringOfFilePathandName:(0 or 1)}**.

The text contains other file extensions (like the .cpp) which I do not need. Also, I do not know the file's encoding so I read it as binary.

My issue shares features with the problems addressed at the links below:

[Python read through file until match, read until next pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421621/python-read-through-file-until-match-read-until-next-pattern)

https://sopython.com/canon/92/extract-text-from-a-file-between-two-markers/ - which I don't quite comprehend

[python - Read file from and to specific lines of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559397/python-read-file-from-and-to-specific-lines-of-text)- this I have tried to copy, but worked for only one instance. I need to iterate this process throughout the file.

Currently I have tried this which works for a single occurence:

```
fileRegex = re.compile(r".*\.cpp")

with open('txfile',"rb") as fin:
   filename = None
   for line in input_data:
       if re.search(fileRegex,str(line)):
           filename = ((re.search(fileRegex,str(line))).group()).lstrip("b'") 
           break
   for line in input_data:
       if (str(line).lstrip("b'").rstrip("\\n'"))=="0" or (str(line).lstrip("b'").rstrip("\\n'"))=="1":
        dictOfFiles[filename] = (str(line).lstrip("b'").rstrip("\\n'"))

   del filename
```

My thinking is that a similar process which iterates through the file is needed. Up till now, the approach I followed was line-by-line. Possibly, it would be better to just save the whole text to a variable and then extract. Any thoughts, are welcome, this has been bugging me for quite a while...

**per request** here's the text file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CGCL-codes/VulDeePecker/master/CWE-119/CGD/cwe119_cgd.txt

Comment: Please provide some real strings

Comment: Are you OK with `{b'stringOfFilePathandName.cpp': b'0', b'stringOfFilePathandName2.cpp': b'1'}` output? Or do you want to have UTF8 strings in the result, like `{'stringOfFilePathandName.cpp': '0', 'stringOfFilePathandName2.cpp': '1'}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, it's fine I can strip it later, thank you

Comment: @Nikos You cannot strip `b` prefix, you need to re-encode the values. See my answer below how to do that.

Comment: @Jan I added a link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
fileRegex = re.compile(rb"^\d+\s+(\S+\.cpp)\s.*(?:\r?\n(?![01]\r?$).*)*\r?\n([10]+)\r?$", re.M)
dictOfFiles = []
with open(r'txfile','rb') as fin:
    dictOfFiles = [(k.decode('utf-8'), (int)(v.decode('utf-8'))) for k, v in fileRegex.findall(fin.read())]
```

Then, `print(dictOfFiles)` returns

```
[('stringOfFilePathandName.cpp': 0), ('stringOfFilePathandName2.cpp': 1)....]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Ou2eb/3).

**NOTES**

- You need to read all the file into a memory for this multiline regex to work, hence I am using `fin.read()`
- When you are reading in a file with a binary mode, CR are not removed, hence I added `\r?` (optional CR) before each `\n`
- To convert byte strings to Unicode strings, we need to use `.decode('utf-8')` on the results.

**Regex details** (in case you need to adjust it later):

- `^` - start of a line (due to `re.M`, `^` matches line start positions)
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+\.cpp)` - Group 1: 1+ non-whitespace chars and then `.cpp`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `.*` - 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:\r?\n(?![01]\r?$).*)*`
- `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF linebreak
- `([10])` - Group 2: a `1` or `0`
- `\r?` - an optional CR
- `$` - end of line.

Comment: I get different total occurrences when running the _filename_ regex (essentially checking how many times does .cpp appear) and your solution(9765 vs 3361). Maybe I omitted or misinterpreted the text format. For replication I added the text file link on the initial post.

Comment: @Nikos The pattern is correct, you just have repeating filenames. If they are not unique, do not use a dictionary, use a list of tuples. I updated the code.

Comment: Oh of course, such ignorance on my part...thank you very much. If I may ask something more, could you please provide a guide/extra resources regarding regex?

Comment: @Nikos I do not know your level of regex knowledge, so I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.

Comment: @NikosH. Hi, I have started uploading some [regex videos on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeq5T-LNtqpVrn_rcJ9hFw), feel free to check them out if you want to learn more about regex. As I am a novice in Youtubing, I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use `re.findall` with a regex pattern which can cope spanning more than one line:

```
input = """1 file1.cpp blah 3
           not needed
           not needed
           2
           ---------------------------------
           9 file1.cpp blah 5
           not needed
           not needed
           3
           ---------------------------------"""
matches = re.findall(r'(\w+\.cpp).*?(\d+)(?=\s+--------)', input, re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('file1.cpp', '2'), ('file1.cpp', '3')]
```

This answer assumes that you can tolerate reading the entire file into memory, and then making one pass with `re.findall`.  If you can't do that, then you will need to continue with your current parsing approach.

Comment: It won't work with the current code because OP is reading the file line by line. `input` must hold the whole file contents. Also, it won't return a dictionary (though it is easy to adjust).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Just noticed that...I added a caveat to my answer.

Comment: I use decode from Wiktor's answer and it seems to work. As you mention I first read the whole file to a variable and the run .findall.